Usage of 別に in this context

はあ、と天道がため息をついた。


「本当、伊波さんの説教凄い迫力あって嫌なんですよ……黒鳥君のお叱りとはまた別にこう……あるんですよ……」


「まあ――そうですね……」


見ている自分もおやと思ったのだ、当事者からしたら二度と相まみえたくない瞬間だったろう。

The character called 天道 got scolded by the character called 伊波.
So he comments

"本当、伊波さんの説教凄い迫力あって嫌なんですよ"

"His sermon have a lot of impact, so I hated it."  Then he adds

"黒鳥君のお叱りとはまた別にこう……あるんですよ……"

"黒鳥君's scolding, still....
I'm unsure how to take こう……あるんですよ…… here. Is it mean to be a negative that got changed at the last minute into an ある? "Your way of scolding is... no actually it is"?
What the actual nuance of また別にこう……ある here?


"黒鳥君のお叱りとはまた別にこう……あるんですよ……"

「～とはまた別に...」 "another... differently/separately from ～～"

「黒島君のお叱りとはまた別に」 -- "another ... differently/separately from Kuroshima-kun's (way of) scolding"
「こう」 -- (used like a filler; used when you don't know how to describe something or how to put something into words) "like..." or "you know..."
「あるんですよ」 -- literally "(something) exists" "There's (something)" "It has (something)."


"黒鳥君's scolding, still....

The subject of this sentence is not 黒島君のお叱り; it's marked with と(は), which is connected to 「別に」. 「～とは別に」 means "differetly from~~" "separately from~~" or "other than~~".
This line is also talking about 伊波さんの説教:

伊波さんの説教(に)は、黒鳥君のお叱りとはまた別にこう……あるんですよ……

"In Inami-san's preaching, there's... like... (some other aspect that I don't know how to describe, which annoys me) differently/separately from Kuroshima-kun's scolding..."
"Inami-san's preaching has... like... (something I can't put into words, which is disturbing) in a different way from Kuroshima-kun's scolding..."
As he's just said 嫌なんですよ in the previous line, here he's talking about some negative aspect in Inami-san's way of preaching.
